# Debugging the code using decorator [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, decorator, python-decorators

I'm writing some code in python to try to create a simple socket object oriented server-client connection. I would like to maintain my code clean hence I would prefer to exclude excessive "if" statement. So my class definition for the server socket look like this:

```
class Server(object):

    def __init__(server_ip=LOCALHOST, server_port=55555, debug=True):

        # other code
        pass
```

so if there is some kind of passage when it would look useful to have some sort of debugging I have included an if statement like the following:

```
if debug:
    print("Something that helps the code debugging")
```

Therefore I have wondered if there was a way to exclude this types of code chunks from the main class and add them to a wrapper function which defines a decorator. Is that possible? And if so, how can I implement this feature?

Thank you very much for your time and also, excuse my english, I am still practising it!

Comment: see https://medium.com/swlh/add-log-decorators-to-your-python-project-84094f832181 for how to implement a logging decorator

Comment: that's what the `logging` module was created for: https://realpython.com/python-logging/

I almost never use print statements anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you, but actually for logging logic it's very convenient to use built-in logging module, which has a clear setup pattern:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log_handler = logging.streamHandler() # to output logs into stderr by default
logger.addHandler(log_handler)

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # here you set log level, you need to parametrize it (or dive deeper into logging docs)

def your_foo():
  logger.debug('Debug log message') # will only fire if log level == DEBUG
```

if you still wanna stick to decorator, I can suggest this talk (part on decorators): [James Powell: So you want to be a Python expert? | PyData Seattle 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKPlPJyQrt4)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Yuriy, I really appriciated your help and, of course, I will look and try using your advices. If I could ask you further help, I have posted another question at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555496/threading-decorator-python. If you could look at it and answer it I would really appreciate. Anyway thank a lot for your help!